# How does initialization of local variables (large arrays) affect stack size?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program where I've to make couple of large integer arrays of 10^6 order on a 4GB RAM machine. Although I've **opted to allocate memory on heap using malloc**. But on defining the arrays statically I'm **getting obviously expected segmentation fault** when the arrays are initialized as below but not when I don't initialize these arrays.

```
#define LIMIT 1000000
#define MOD 1000000007

using namespace std;



void prime_seive(vector<int> &primes)
{
    int i, j;
    bool prime_no[LIMIT+1];
    int m=sqrt(LIMIT);
    // Something else

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> primes;
    prime_seive(primes);

    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);    
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);

        int a[n+1];
        for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }

        int fact_arr[LIMIT+1]={0};  // Segmentation fault when I initialize arrays
        int part_arr[LIMIT+1]={0};  // Segmentation fault when I initialize arrays
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

But without initialization

```
int fact_arr[LIMIT+1];  // NO Segmentation fault here.
int part_arr[LIMIT+1];  // NO Segmentation fault here.
```

I don't get any kind of segmentation fault error.

So out of curiosity I'd like to understand what difference initializing the array is making here ?

EDIT 1: 
Okay so I added `cout<<fact_arr[0]<<fact_arr[1]<<endl;` at the end and which does print 00 for those indexes of the array. So this certainly seems to be a dangerous resort to not initialize your arrays

Comment: stack is in RAM also isn't it?

Comment: Yes. What are you suggesting ?

Comment: have you tried using the arrays in some way, e.g. displaying first item.

Comment: So use dynamic allocations for large arrays. your stack overflow.

Comment: @SHR: Did you read the second sentence of the OP's post?

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf They are gonna contain garbage if not initialized and zeros if initialised. But that's not important.

Comment: @a4anurag: garbage is fine, the values don't matter. it's the access (and call) that matters, to test your implicit hypothesis that it's the initialization that's crucial.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf Okay so I added 
cout<<fact_arr[0]<<fact_arr[1]<<endl;
at the end and which does print 00 for those indexes of the array. So this certainly seems to be a dangerous resort to not initialize your arrays.

Comment: So you're saying that you added output of some items of the initialized arrays, and then you *did not* get a segfault but instead it "does print 00 for those indexes of the array". That sounds a bit inconsistent.

Comment: No, I added the output for the non-initialized arrays. Which seems to be a dangerous resort.

Now I need one more clarification. Why does the segfault(where arrays are initialized) doesn't wait for use input as what is expected from scanf() above the array definition? Does compiler first does the stack allocation for all local variables before it starts executing the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A segmentation fault is caused when you attempt to access memory in a way that you don't have permission for.  Without the array initializer, no access has occurred.<sup>*</sup>

However, that code is still precipitous.  For example, if you were to call a function immediately afterwards, it *would* lead to stack accesses.

---

<sub>* Alternatively, the compiler may simply have chosen to optimise those variables away.</sub>

Comment: re "Without the array initializer, no access occurs." that's a bit misleading. an *unused* variable can be optimized away. that appears to be what's going on without the initializer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't think it's necessarily related to optimization.  The compiler may still shift the stack pointer (or whatever) to account for those variables, but nothing gets written to that memory.

Comment: well if the stack pointer is shifted then any call of a routine after those declarations, should segfault. so then, still not the access in itself (because then no access involved).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Agreed.  I'll adjust wording accordingly.

Comment: Okay so the way I understand is I don't get any error in case without initialization is because there is no validation on the allocated memory when program is run. Laziness of the C compiler to provide more efficiency. But when initialization is being done, all the bytes are being initialized which might cause the out of bound illegal access. @Oli Charlesworth: Correct me if I understood it wrong or would like to add something to it.

Comment: @a4anurag: That's essentially it.  There's no reason for the compiler to generate code to check for stack overflow; the hardware already performs that check.

Comment: Yes but if I want to catch such bugs in the test phase itself rather than in production I believe its always a wise idea to initialize variables. Otherwise this seems to be quite dangerous thing as doing cout<<fact_arr[0]<<fact_arr[1]<<endl; afterwards does prints 00 which seems to be valid. Tests may pass but certainly the code is a time bomb without initialization.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth
Now I need one more clarification. Why does the segfault(where arrays are initialized) doesn't wait for use input as what is expected from scanf() above the array definition? Does compiler first does the stack allocation and initialization for all local variables before it starts executing the program?